no bumps on the object
I'm not a Unity pro and started making my first 2D game.
In this script, a ray is released from the point towards the cursor, and if it hits the hook, then one part of the rope is created.
using UnityEngine;

public class ThrowRope : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _hook;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _unitRopePref;
    [SerializeField] private Transform _player;



    void Update()
    {
        if (Button.nuberPerson == 2)
        {

            if (Cursorrender.cursRopeMode)
            {

                Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
                RaycastHit hit;
                Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 100, Color.red);
                if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
                {
                    Debug.Log("CLICK");
                    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
                    {
                        Debug.Log("HIT");
                        if (hit.distance <= 200 && hit.collider.gameObject == _hook)
                        {
                            Debug.Log("INSTANTIATE");
                            Instantiate(_unitRopePref, hit.transform);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

But after opening the game and pressing the mouse key, the code only reaches the CLICK message, even if the ray should hit the object.

Are your colliders 2D or 3D? Physics.Raycast will only hit 3D colliders, for 2D colliders you'd need Physics2D.Raycast. Though for your use case it sounds like you would rather get the cursor position (which so far isn't happening at all in your code - e.g. using Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint) and then use a Physics2D.LineCast to check whether therr is a valid object between your position and the cursor world space position

If the ray is suppose to go to the cursor (from the point of view of the camera), use ScreenPointToRay from the viewing camera.
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
{
    var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit))
    {
        Debug.Log($"Hit {hit.collider.name}");
    }
}

You can replace Camera.main with a reference to your camera, or cache the main camera if needed (micro optimization).
